# "No sooner had ... than" and "No sooner did ... than"

Tags: inversion, past-vs-past-perfect, negative-inversion

Are both of the following sentences grammatically correct?

> - No sooner **had** the committee made the announcement than everyone started complaining
> - No sooner **did** the committee made the announcement than everyone started complaining

Comment: no, so can you work out which one isn't and why...

Comment: They are both syntactically sound.